# Form not sending email after specific zipcode

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, google-maps

Good evening,

this is rather a strange happening here.
I have a form on automaker.nl which will ask quotes for car reparations. It works for everyone except for some of the zipcodes.

If the form has been filled in wrong, it will give an error with the explenation what went wrong. But for this zipcode the page just refreshes and gives me the 'email not send' message.

Okay, if you go to automaker.nl and fill in a Dutch licenseplate for example SL-SL-81 then choose a subject for your reparation.
The next page will automatically fill in the car details because of the licenseplate which was filled in.
Here the strange problem occurs.
If you fill in all information (Dutch information) and fill in postcode (zipcode) as 9074EB no problems occur and email has been send. Now if I fill in excactly the same information except the zipcode is now 6524MS it gives me this message without an error. Just not sending anything.

The code for the zipcode is:

```
require_once ('classes/GoogleMapsApi.php');
require_once ('classes/Distance.php');
$distance = new Distance();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit_reparation'])) {
$_POST['Image1'] = '';

if(!empty($_FILES['Image1'])) {
    $upload = new Upload();
    $upload->setDestination(__DIR__ . '/uploads');
    $upload->setFilename($_FILES['Image1']['name']);
    $upload->setPromission(644);
    $_POST['Image1'] = $upload->saveImage($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']);
}

if(empty($_POST['Title'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen titel ingevuld";
}
if(empty($_POST['Merk'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen auto merk geselecteerd";
}
if(empty($_POST['Handelsbenaming'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen model geselecteerd";
}
if(empty($_POST['open_rdw-921'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen kenteken ingevuld";
}
if(empty($_POST['Name'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen naam ingevuld";
}
if(empty($_POST['Email'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen e-mailadres ingevuld";
}
if(!filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen correct e-mailadres ingevuld";
}

if(empty($_POST['Zipcode'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen postcode ingevuld";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['latitude'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen correcte postcode ingevuld";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['longitude'])) {
    $error[] = "U heeft geen correcte postcode ingevuld";
}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?([a-zA-Z]{2})?$/', $_POST['Zipcode'])){
    $error[] = "U heeft geen correcte postcode ingevuld";
}

if (count($error) <= 0) {
    $pass = wp_generate_password ( 12, false );
    $register = array(
        'Title'            =>   $_POST['Title'],
        'Zipcode'            => $_POST['Zipcode'],
        'Description'        => $_POST['Description'],
        'Merk'             =>   $_POST['Merk'],
        'Handelsbenaming'    => $_POST['Handelsbenaming'],
        'LicensePlate'     =>   $_POST['open_rdw-921'],
        'Name'             =>   $_POST['Name'],
        'Phone'            =>   $_POST['Phone'],
        'Email'            =>   $_POST['Email'],
        'Latitude'         =>   $_POST['latitude'],
        'Longitude'        =>   $_POST['longitude'],
              'City'                 => $_POST['City'],
        'Image1'             => $_POST['Image1'],
        'Hash'             => md5(time()),
    );

    $wpdb->insert('Reparation', $register);

    if ($wpdb->insert_id) {
        $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation.html');
        $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%DESCRIPTION%', $_POST['Description'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%BRAND%', $_POST['Merk'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%MODEL%', $_POST['Handelsbenaming'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%LICENSEPLATE%', $_POST['open_rdw-921'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%NAME%', $_POST['Name'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%EMAIL%', $_POST['Email'], $message);
        $message = str_replace('%PHONE%', $_POST['Phone'], $message);
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n");
        wp_mail($_POST['Email'], 'Uw reparatie op Automaker.nl is succesvol verzonden', $message, $headers);

        $success = "Bedankt! Uw aanvraag is succesvol verstuurd. U zult snel offertes ontvangen.";

        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'aamrole_5404aaeed25c7' ) );
              $Allbrands = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT allemerken FROM wp_users", OBJECT);
        $emails = array();
        if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
            foreach ($user_query->results as $user) {
                $user_account_type = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'account_type', true );

                $emails[] = $user->user_email;
                $point1 = array('lat' => $_POST['latitude'], 'long' => $_POST['longitude']);
                $point2 = array('lat' => $user->latitude, 'long' => $user->longitude);
                $retvalDistance = $distance->getDistance($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);
                if($user_account_type != 3){
                  if ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $Allbrands[0]->allemerken == 1) {
                      $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                      $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                      $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                      $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                      if(!wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers)){
                        die("mail did not send");
                      }
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk1 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk2 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk3 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk4 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk5 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk6 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk7 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk8 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk9 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                  }
                            elseif ($retvalDistance <= $automaker['application']['distance'] && $user->Merk10 == $_POST['Merk']) {
                                $message = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/reparation_garage.html');
                                $message = str_replace('%TITLE%', $_POST['Title'], $message);
                                $message = str_replace('%GARAGE%', $user->company_name, $message);
                                $headers = 'From: Automaker.nl <info@automaker.nl>' . "\r\n";
                                wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Er is een nieuwe reparatie geplaatst op Automaker.nl!', $message, $headers);
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Distance.php is as follows:

```
class Distance {

public function getDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)
{

    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $pi80;
    $lon1 *= $pi80;
    $lat2 *= $pi80;
    $lon2 *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlon = $lon2 - $lon1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlon / 2) * sin($dlon / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c;

    return $km;
}}
```

And GoogleMapsAPi.php is as follows:

```
class GoogleMapsApi
{
    const MAPS_HOST = 'maps.google.com';

    protected $_latitude;
    protected $_longitude;
    protected $_address;
    protected $_countryName;
    protected $_countryNameCode;
    protected $_administrativeAreaName;
    protected $_postalCode;
    protected $_key;
    protected $_baseUrl;

    public function __construct ()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getInfoLocation ($address) {
        if (!empty($address)) {
            return $this->execute($address);
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * connect to Google Maps
     *
     * @param string $param
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function execute($param) {
        $cityclean = str_replace (" ", "+", $param);
        $details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $cityclean . "&components=country:Nederland&sensor=false";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $geoloc = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

        return $geoloc;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out, hope someone knows a solution.

Comment: This seems to be having the problem, but I am uncertain what is activating the problem. The zipcode input field class is 'googlemapapi'.

Comment: Try use developer tool to inspect network traffic and compare the requests body sent before and after changing the post code. And also compare the responses